# How to transfer data between 2 frames in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 6.5.1 to create an application that involves transferring data between 2 frames, I mean the user will enter the data in the first frame and the data entered must be transferred to the second frame, without making the second frame visible. The second frame will not be visible initially and even after getting the data from the first frame it must not become visible till a certain button(from a different frame of the same project) is pressed. I tried overloading the constructor, but when I'm calling the method in frame-1 I'm unable to just store the data (and display it in a jLabel). I can only do this by using the setVisible() method as ( *new Frame2(data_to_be_transferred).setVisible(true);* ). This method does the job **but it makes the second frame visible** with the data. So how do I transfer the data between 2 frames without making the second frame visible?

Comment: You can save data in the field and then pass it to JLable or whatever, and it won’t be related to your Frame

Comment: How do I _save_ the data then?

Answer (score 0):

You could either create your frame with the data *Frame2 f2 = new Frame2*(data_to_be_transferred); and then make it visible only when needed via *f2.setVisible(true);*

OR

keep your data to be transferred and only create the frame2 later on when really needed and make it immediately visible as you're already doing *new Frame2*(data_to_be_transferred)*.setVisible(true);*

Cheers!

Comment: Okay..... But how do I call the operator method that will transfer the data?

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
public class SomeClass extends JFrame {
 JPanel panel;
 JTextField textField;
 JButton button;
 JLabel label;
 String data;
 SomeClass() {
  panel = new JPanel();
  textField = new JTextField(16);
  button = new JButton("Magic");
  label = new JLabel();
  panel.add(button);
  panel.add(textField);
  setContentPane(panel);
  setSize(400,100);
  setVisible(true);
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SomeClass();
 }
button.addActionListener(e ->{
  data = textField.getText();
  if((data == null) || (data.equals(""))){
   return;
   }else {
   this.remove(panel)
   JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
   label = new JLabel();
   panel.add(label);
   this.setContentPane(panel2);
   label.setText(data);
   }
 });
}
```

Sorry, I confused.. you can create new **JFrame** instance in actionPerformed or as I did in **e->** which is lambda expression.

```
public class AnotherClass extends JFrame {
 JPanel panel;
 JLabel label;
 AnotherClass() {
  panel = new JPanel();
  label = new JLabel();
  panel.add(label);
  setContentPane(panel);
  setSize(400,100);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

And then thought reference of AnotherClass ( frame 2 ) set value for label.

```
    button.addActionListener(e ->{
  data = textField.getText();
  if((data == null) || (data.equals(""))){
   return;
   }else {
AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
anotherClass.label.setText(data);
   }
 });
```